# IIS: published asp.net mvc application throws: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, fullcalendar

After going bonkers over it for half the day I finally decided to post a question. In my production project; I had two `input type=date` fields (StarDate, EndDate), getting the values and making an ajax request to controller's action worked fine, I decided to replace the date types with a jquery `daterangepicker` [Predefined Ranges Date Range picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), I got the values from it, broke down and passed the two dates through the same ajax call, and it worked like a charm, now when I published the project through IIS and tried to access it on local network, it throws this error in the Console Network.

The problem occurs (in local network) when I click on the submit button, work fine on initialize (no button press).

Working snippet (in prod)
Index.cshtml

```
<input type ="hidden" id="startDate" name="startDate" style="border: 2px solid #32c5d2; border-radius: 4px;" required ="required"/>
@*<b>End Date</b>*@
<input  type ="hidden"id="endDate" name="endDate" style="border: 2px solid #32c5d2; border-radius: 4px;" required ="required"  /> @*max=todaysDate*@
<input type="button" value="submit" class="btn green" id="btnGet"  style="float:right; margin-left:20px;" name="btnGet" onclick="h()"/>

<div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 50%">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span id="reportRange" name ="reportRange"></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
```

JScipts:

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';

function h() {
    var x = document.getElementById("reportRange").innerText;

    console.log(" currentEmpID: " + id);
    s = $("#startDate").val();
    e = $("#endDate").val();

    console.log("After dates");
    console.log("date Range: " + x);

    var res = x.split("-");
    console.log("After split: " + res);

    a = res[0], b = res[1];
    console.log("CompStats a: " + a);
    console.log("CompStats b: " + b);

    var sDate = new Date(a);
    var eDate = new Date(b);

    s = (sDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + sDate.getDate() + '/' + sDate.getFullYear();
    e = (eDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + eDate.getDate() + '/' + eDate.getFullYear();

    console.log("CompStats SS: " + s);
    console.log("CompStats EE: " + e);
    console.log("start: " + s);
    console.log("end: " + e);

    $.post(baseUrl + "Stats/completeStats",
    {
        EnrollNumber: id,
        StartDate: s,
        EndDate: e
    },
    function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusList);

        var items = "";

        $.each(response.statusList, function (a, b) {            
            items += '<p><b>' + b + '</b></p>';
        });                   

        $("#StatusList").html(items);
        callCalendar(response.list);           
    });
}
```

JS:

```
function callCalendar(e)
{
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({            
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',      
            right: 'month,agendaDay,basicWeek,listWeek'
        },
        //.. so on
}
```

JS (initialize) (works fine on both prod and local network):

```
{
    id = $('.selected-item').val();
    id = @Session["currentEmpID"].ToString()

    console.log(" currentEmpID: " + id);

    console.log("inital S: " + s);
    console.log("initial E: " + e);

    // Return today's date and time
    var currentTime = new Date()

    // returns the month (from 0 to 11)
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1

    // returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31)
    var endingDay = currentTime.getDate()

    // returns the year (four digits)
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

    var s1 = new Date(year, month - 1, 1); //Thu Feb 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

    s1.getMonth() + 1  // 01
    s1.getDate()     // 02
    s1.getFullYear() // 2018

    console.log("Inital starting date: " + s1);

    var s = (s1.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + s1.getDate() + "/" + s1.getFullYear();   //behtreen cheypi
    console.log("starting date: " + s);

    var e='@DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString()';
    console.log("Initial ending date: " + e);

    $.post(baseUrl + "Stats/Initialize",
    {
        EnrollNumber: id,
        StartDate:s,
        EndDate: e
    },
    function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusList);
        var items = "";

        $.each(response.statusList, function (a, b) {                  
            items += '<tr><b>' + b + '</b></tr>';
        });

        $("#StatusList").html(items);
        callCalendar(response.list);
    });
}
```

Controller:

Action 1 (initialize)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Initialize(int EnrollNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, MyClass mC)
{ //.. }
```

Action 2 (completeStats)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult completeStats(int EnrollNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, MyClass mC)
{ //.. }
```

[image]

[image]

What have I tried?

I know the values are being passed to the action (double-tripled checked) I even tried to change the date typews to nullables in the controller it then threw the "must have value" exception (obviously this isnt whats wrong).

I have been going crazy over why is this happening, when t works fine in the build, (both initialize and completeStats) but in the local access (after publishing) only the initialze method works fine (values passed and calendar populates) but when the request to completeStats is sent it throws the exception. Again, I am passing the dates (start/end) but it throws the null error! UGH! :/

Comment: you should pass your dates in an unambiguous format such as ISO8601 (i.e. basically yyyy-mm-dd format). Otherwise it's not guaranteed to be clear to the server whether you meant dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy. the JS Date object and momentJS both have methods to output that format automatically without building it by hand, and C#'s DateTime object can do the same. If you had a date such as "03/01/2018" it would be completely unclear to the server whether you mean 1st March or 3rd January.

Comment: Possibly the reason it works locally and not on the server could be due to the localisation or culture settings of the server vs the client, but anyway to get round that just use a non-culture-specific date format which you know will always be parseable by the model binder.

Comment: `you should pass your dates in an unambiguous format such as ISO8601 (i.e. basically yyyy-mm-dd format). Otherwise it's not guaranteed to be clear to the server whether you meant dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy.` how exactly in the code? (completeStats method is the one that throws this exception)

Comment: As I already mentioned - "the JS Date object and momentJS both have methods to output that format" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: So I should try sending it in the ISO format? like `toISOString());`

Comment: Yes exactly. Then there's never any doubt for the server about what you mean.

Comment: I just tried this, by `var sDate = new Date(a);
            var eDate = new Date(b);
            //console.log("sDate: " + sDate.toDateString());
            console.log("CompStats SS before ISO: " + sDate);
            sDate.toISOString();
            eDate.toISOString();
            console.log("CompStats SS after ISO: " + sDate);` no changes whatsoever helped.

Comment: `CompStats SS before ISO: Thu Feb 22 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
CompStats SS after ISO: Thu Feb 22 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)`

Comment: Try `console.log(sDate.toISOString());` to actually see the ISO string. It doesn't mutate the Date object (because the date object is obviously an object containing some numbers, it's not a string in any given format, so you can't change it to another format...), instead that method returns a string in the ISO format. There was even a demo of usage on that link I gave you, you were intended to actually read it!

Comment: @ADyson okay but why does it changes the date? `CompStats SS before ISO: Tue Jan 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
CompStats SS after ISO: 2018-01-29T19:00:00.000Z`

Comment: It doesn't, it just shows it in a different timezone. Again, read the docs.

Comment: Of course since you're using fullCalendar which uses momentJS, we can shortcut this whole nonsense: `$.post(baseUrl + "Stats/completeStats",
                {
                    EnrollNumber: id,
                    StartDate: moment(a).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                    EndDate: moment(b).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                },` . http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/